# Why am I getting: "stackoverflow.com connection is untrusted "alerts?

Tags: support, ssl

When trying to reach **www.stackoverflow.com** domain I'm getting warnings both

**in Chrome:**
[image: chrome alert]

**and Firefox:**
[image]

- Why am I getting these alerts?
- How do you know if the issue, whatever it may be, is on their end or on the users end?
- And should  the user proceed or not?

Comment: SE is changing certificates due to the Heartbleed vulnerability, I'd guess this has something to do with it.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the info, should I delete my question now?

Comment: It's still useful for anyone else asking this same question